# Can you have a function on the device that can be called from a kernel

Tags: aleagpu

Apologies - I'm a newbie to AleaGPU.  I have a function that I would like to be able to call from several different kernels.  Is it possible to put a function on the device that can be called from different kernels - I've scoured the documentation but can't find the relevant part - maybe because I don't know what its called.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly call function from kernel, there is no need for things like `__device__` in AleaGpu.